# How to generate 'non-deterministic' hashes in Node.js from the same secret?

Tags: node.js, cryptography

From a given secret:

```
const SECRET = 'default'
```

I know that I can deterministically create a hash:

```
import { createHmac } from 'crypto'
const hash = createHmac('sha256', SECRET).digest('base64')

// pUl0ESYi3V4+6QVsPlBEf1sDfV4IyIM80hggueAEAxA=
```

I understand that by being 'deterministic', the output of `createHmac('sha256', SECRET).digest('base64')`  will always be that same value.

I want to generate hashes **non** deterministically, then I want to be able to validate that each of these hashes was created using `SECRET`:

```
const hash1 = createHash('sha256', SECRET).digest('base64')
const hash2 = createHash('sha256', SECRET).digest('base64')
const hash3 = createHash('sha256', SECRET).digest('base64')
const hash4 = createHash('sha256', SECRET).digest('base64')
const hash5 = createHash('sha256', SECRET).digest('base64')

hash1 !== hash2 !== hash3 !== hash4 !== hash5 // true

validate(hash1, SECRET) // true
validate(hash2, SECRET) // true
validate(hash3, SECRET) // true
validate(hash4, SECRET) // true
validate(hash5, SECRET) // true
validate(hash5, 'other value') // false
```

How can I do this using the Node.js `crypto` module? Also, I guess that this falls broadly under under 'asymmetric encryption'? It feels similar to the idea of using SSH private/public keys. What is this called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is commonly done with a salt:

- Choose a random series of bytes (for example, 8)
- Prepend (or append) the bytes to the data to be hashed (SECRET)
- Apply hash
- Store salt + hash

Validation uses the same salt.

A more advanced form of this is a KDF (key derivation function). The most famous, and a good general choice, is [PBKDF2](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback). PBKDF2 is very time consuming, which is intentional, to make brute forcing difficult.

Comment: Ah I see. I had not understood what a salt is before. Thank you